# Hiding the root for OOTB BreadCrumb navigation

Tags: navigation

We have a site collection that has language variations. So a breadcrumb might look like this

```
Root > English > Products > Page Title
```

We can using the sites title and description play around with the label for the language variation root so it looks like this

```
Root > Home > Products > Page Title
```

But the problem is hiding the root of the breadcrumb. The code looks something like this

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBreadcrumb" runat="server">
    <div id="master-page-breadcrumb">
        <asp:SiteMapPath    
            runat="server"                          
            SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" 
            NodeStyle-CssClass="SolidBreadCrumb"
            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="SolidBreadCrumbCurrent"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="SolidBreadCrumbRoot"
            HideInteriorRootNodes="false"
            SkipLinkText=""/>
    </div>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Using the RootNodeStyle and CSS you can hide the root no problem using the following CSS

```
<style>.HideRootNode { display:none; }</style>
```

The problem is this leaves you with a breadcrumb like this

```
> Home > Products > Page Title
```

The divider/separator is still there. What we are looking for is something like this

```
Home > Products > Page Title
```

There has to be some kind of simple option that I am missing. Also just to note, I am not a .NET developer so writing my own control or something is not an option.

I am going to start looking at jQuery to try and figure something out, but thought I would just get it out there in case I am missing something.

Thanks ... Mike

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Everyone looking to solve this problem. Here is what we did to hide the root link of the site collection using jQuery ...

```
<!--[ Breadcrumb ]------------->
<!----------------------------->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBreadcrumb" runat="server">
    <div id="master-page-breadcrumb">
        <asp:SiteMapPath    
            ID="contentNavigation"
            runat="server"  
            SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
            NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode"
            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode"
            HideInteriorRootNodes="false"
            SkipLinkText="">
            <RootNodeTemplate></RootNodeTemplate>
        </asp:SiteMapPath>
    </div>
    <style>.HideRootNode { display:none; }</style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            var rootNode = $("span[id$=contentNavigation] > span:eq(0)");
            if (rootNode.attr("class") == "breadcrumbRootNode") {   
                rootNode.hide();
                $(rootNode).next("span").css('display', 'none'); }
        });
    </script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<!-- ---------------- -->
```

Thanks goes to Jeremiah Walker from Imaginet for this one. Hope it works for everyone who needs this.

Comment: no other config level changes can be done to achieve this?
i am trying to avoid client side scripts to do this

Answer (score 0):

Having not looked at the html/css, the first css only idea that came to mind is using the css:first-child selector: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

If you can't do it that way you could do it in jQuery pretty easily.

Comment: That is the next play, tried the first child, but that leaves the '>' just hanging at the start. Will post back when I got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit CSS file:

```
a.breadcrumbRootNode {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

this CSS class already implemented in SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider.